# Unable to focus QR code using Mobile Vision API

Tags: android, camera, focus, qr-code, vision

I am using Google Mobile Vision API in my Android Application to scan QR codes. The scanning is absolutely fine.

In some phones, the focus is not proper. In Galaxy S4, I have to move the phone back and forth to scan.

The below line is in build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0'
```

This is how I create the CameraSource.

```
cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build();
```

Though the auto focus is set to true, the QR code is not focused.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flag ***FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE*** in function *setFocusMode*

```
cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setFocusMode(autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build();
```

Comment: There is no method setFocusMode in CameraSource

Comment: add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.2'`

Comment: Still the same. Cannot resolve the method setFocusMode()

Comment: use sample code provided by google here is [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java)

Comment: This is a custom CameraSource code, not the one available in the API.

Comment: Do you why this is not in the API or do you when will this be added to the API?